Objective C ARC: _foo in constructor autoincrements or not?
a bit related to In Objective-C MRR, if foo is a retain property, then self.foo = [[Foo alloc] init] will need to be released immediately?
suppose you have
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) NSObject *foo;

In this case
- (instancetype)initWithSomeObject:(NSObject)foo
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        _foo = foo;
    }
}

would foo correctly get autoincremented as retain property attribute suggests it should?
I initially wrote this as self.foo = foo; but for some reason folks on the team use the compact syntax that seemed more fitting in MRC times to avoid superfluous release for a n object newly created in the init context.

you just need @property (nonatomic) NSObject *foo;

For ARC it's ok and Apple recommends to use ivar directly in initializers. For example you have overridden setFoo: and it's behaviour is depending on some property of children class, but at the line self.froo = foo in the parent class initializer it's not set yet.
